# Rasterio read function producing uniform array or near-zero values for a non-uniform raster

Tags: python, rasterio

I have been looking all over the internet for a possible cause of this, but without luck, and was hoping it's some standard Rasterio quirk that I just can't track down. I am trying to load the Tanzania poverty map from World Pop, which is a 1km resolution raster grid of population rates (available [here](http://www.worldpop.org.uk/data/summary/?contselect=Africa&countselect=United+Republic+of+Tanzania&typeselect=Poverty)). Values for each grid square can be between 0 and 1, and the raster looks like this:

[image: tanzania worldpop raster in qgis]

Using the following Python code I've been loading the raster with Rasterio:

```
import os
import rasterio

file_path = os.path.abspath('path/to/tza10povcons125.tif')
raster = rasterio.open(file_path)
band = raster.read(1)
```

Based on my understanding of Rasterio, I would expect the `band` variable to contain a 2 dimensional array of values between `0` and `1` (or, rather, `0.664994` and `0.950991`, which are the min and max values according to QGIS). However, when I print out the `band` variable I see:

```
array([[ -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38, ...,
         -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38],
       [ -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38, ...,
         -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38],
       [ -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38, ...,
         -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38],
       ..., 
       [ -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38, ...,
         -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38],
       [ -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38, ...,
         -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38],
       [ -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38, ...,
         -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38,  -3.39999995e+38]], dtype=float32)
```

The recurring value, `-3.39999995e+38`, is also suspiciously close to the minimum value for numpy's `float32` datatype:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.finfo('float32').min
-3.4028235e+38
```

I am just wondering if anyone has seen this kind of behaviour for Rasterio before, or if there is something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably those `-3.39999995e+38` are [NO_DATA](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/nodata-in-raster-datasets.htm) values of the raster. In rasterio you can check which cells have NO_DATA values [using a mask](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/masks.html).

```
msk = raster.read_masks(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. Similarly, seeing now that `raster.meta` shows (among other things): `'nodata': -3.4e+38`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to identify a NODATA value:

```
print(raster.nodata)
```